# Add info in cell without affect its value

Tags: google-sheets, join, replace, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to show more information in one single cell but without altering its actual value.

For exemple 
A2 is an addition
A2 = 40+10
Showed: A2 = 50

But I want to have this showed:
« 50 (40+10) » (the actual formula)

A2 keeps the value « 50 » but show me the actual maths behind

Is this possible?

Comment: There is an option in Excel called "Show Formulas" which I think does what you want.

Comment: In Google Sheets or Excel? They're similar, but different products with different built-in options/functions.  In Excel, the shortcut to show formulas is `CTRL+\``.  Alternatively, you can use `=FORMULATEXT(A2)`.

Comment: I dont want to see my formula in my cell because it will be something more like that
```A1 = 40 A2 = 10
A3 = A1 + A2
```
It will normaly write : A3 = 50 but I want to see the actual math + the result like 
`A3 = 50 (40+10)`

Comment: You will need code to do what you want.  And as such the approach will be unique to Google Sheets.

Comment: Or by a simple comment when I hover the cell for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the same cell:

```
=40+10&" (40+10)"
```

[image: 0]

---

in a side cell:

```
=A2&" ("&REPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A2), 1, 1, )&")"
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This solution seems to work but the conditional formatting dont recognize the cells as a value but for now its the best solution so far